# jQuery mouseover from an array

Tags: jquery

I have made a div called navarea and inside it I have 6 more div's. When I mouse over I want to change there background color.

I dont want to have 6 mouse over functions for each div, instead I want to get the names of the divs from an array.

I can change the background colour without the mouseover function in this way, but as soon as I add the mouseover function it does absolutely nothing.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Bill

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {



var mainnav=["dashboard","sales","marketing","production","accounts","logout"];


jQuery.each(mainnav, function() {

$("#" + this).mouseover(function(){ // Why is this line is failing?
$("#" + this).css("background-color","#8c9aa0");
});  

});


});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#navarea {
height: auto;
width: 180px;
background-color:#FFF;
}

#dashboard {
height: auto;
width: 180px;
background-color:#FFF;
}


</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navarea">
<div id="dashboard">Dashboard</div>
<div id="sales">Sales</div>
<div id="marketing">Marketing</div>
<div id="production">Production</div>
<div id="accounts">Accounts</div>
<div id="logout">Logout</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you dont use the CSS `:hover` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the each function improperly. If the `div`s you want to target are within a parent element (for this example, let's say the parent element is `mainnav`), then you should just do this:

```
$("#mainnav").children().each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","#8c9aa0");
  }, function(){
    $(this).css("background-color","[insert mouseout color here]");
  });
});
```

1. The .hover() function lets you place both the mouseover and mouseout elements in the same function, as you can see above. This minimizes code.
2. `$("#" + this)` makes no sense, as `$(this)` in jQuery selects the active element.
3. I used the `.children()` function. All this does is select the elements nested within the selected element, in this case `#mainnav`.

More about `.each()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and more about `.children()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the CSS `:hover` class to change the background color:

```
#navarea div:hover {
    background-color: #8c9aa0;
}
```

Also, you cant use an each loop to set a mouseover listener. The mouseover function wont work. Within jQuery code, you should also use `$(this)` as opposed to `this`. Try this code, all though the example shown above in CSS would be way more efficient:

```
   $('#navarea div').mouseover(function(){
      $(this).css("backgroundColor","#8c9aa0");
   });
```